# Update labels text inside of a foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
foreach ($question['a'] as $a) {
    ?>
    <div class="radio">   
            <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer" value="<?php echo $count ?>"><label id="answerLabel" for="answer"><?php echo $a['name'] ?> </label>
            <?php $count = $count + 1; ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

```js
$.ajax({
    ///url,data etc
    success: function (data) {
        $('#index').val(data.index);
        $answers = data.question.a;
        $answers.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log(item['name']);
            $('#answerLabel').html(item['name']);
        })
    }   
});
```

I'm trying to update the label text inside the foreach loop but only the first value updates and the  radio button also disappears. The console log show 4 items as it should.

var_dump of questions['a']:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["questionId"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "correct"
    ["correct"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["questionId"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "correct"
    ["correct"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["questionId"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "correct"
    ["correct"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["questionId"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "correct"
    ["correct"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

Based on the answer of  jameshwart lopez, I appended the $count to the id of the label then made a count =1 in the ajax and added 1 in  the foreachloop.
This solved the problem.

Comment: what does this show you?  `var_dump($question['a'])` ?  Please edit your post with the value

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Id's are for unique elements only.in your case `answerLabel` you can try to concat the name or add something to that id that will make it unique element.

Sample

```
    $count =0;
    foreach ($question['a'] as $a) {
        ?>
        <div class="radio">   
                <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer<?php echo $count;?>" value="<?php echo $count ?>"><label id="answerLabel<?php echo $count;?>" for="answer"><?php echo $a['name'] ?> </label>
                <?php $count = $count + 1; ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>




           $.ajax({
                ///url,data etc
                success: function (data) {

                    $('#index').val(data.index);
                    $answers = data.question.a;
                    count =0;
                    $answers.forEach(function(item) {
                        console.log(item['name']);
                        $('#answerLabel'+count).html(item['name']);
                        count = count+1;
                    })
                }     

        });
```

hope that helps.

Comment: You have radio buttons with the same ID within the foreach loop

Comment: im sorry, I have missed that part also.though i have udpated my answer.

Comment: So it's done. If you modify your label id to append the count var instead a['name'] and  use a count in the success as well I'll mark it as answer.